# Sql increment count conditional value row by row

Tags: sql, count

```
n   id  Name    ShipDate    Pfit
1   1   apple   2018-04-14  +   
2   1   apple   2018-04-15  +   
3   1   apple   2018-04-16  +   
4   1   apple   2018-04-17  -   
5   1   apple   2018-04-18  -   
1   2   bread   2018-04-14  -   
2   2   bread   2018-04-15  -   
3   2   bread   2018-04-16  +   
1   3   orange  2018-04-14  +   
2   3   orange  2018-04-15  +   
3   3   orange  2018-04-16  -   
1   4   tomato  2018-04-14  +   
2   4   tomato  2018-04-15  -   
3   4   tomato  2018-04-16  -
```

I want to increment count the ( + ) or ( - )  in the Pfit column for each item and this result as serial column
How do i do it ?
(This is what I want to be) (Mssql 2012)

```
n   id  Name    ShipDate    Pfit Serial
1   1   apple   2018-04-14  +       1
2   1   apple   2018-04-15  +       2
3   1   apple   2018-04-16  +       3
4   1   apple   2018-04-17  -       1
5   1   apple   2018-04-18  -       2
1   2   bread   2018-04-14  -       1
2   2   bread   2018-04-15  -       2
3   2   bread   2018-04-16  +       1
1   3   orange  2018-04-14  +       1
2   3   orange  2018-04-15  +       2
3   3   orange  2018-04-16  -       1
1   4   tomato  2018-04-14  +       1
2   4   tomato  2018-04-15  -       1
3   4   tomato  2018-04-16  -       2
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  This is a fairly complex query, we need to know the version of SQL.

Comment: Mssql server 2012

Comment: Question: Can minus/plus ever occur _more_ than once within an `id` group?  Your data does not have this happening..but can it happen?

Comment: No. plus / minus mean only one item of profit or loss
but if so, what do you need to do?

Comment: It means the query needed to get the right answer might change.  It becomes more of a gaps and islands problem.

Comment: Ok. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by @ITWeiHan would work under the assumption that there can only be at most a single +/- within each `id` group.  If there could be *multiple* pluses/minuses, then we would need to do more work.  One safe approach would be to use the difference in row numbers method:

```
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY n) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, Pfit ORDER BY n) rn
    FROM cte
)

SELECT n, id, name, ShipDate, Pfit,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, rn ORDER BY n) AS Serial
FROM cte2
ORDER BY
    id, n;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note carefully that I have modified your sample data such that `id=1` has two sets of plus records.

Answer (score 0):

**use this script:**

```
select * 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [id], [Name],[Pfit] ORDER BY [ShipDate] asc)  as Serial
from TempTable
```

**test data :**

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable
    ([n] int, [id] int, [Name] varchar(6), [ShipDate] datetime, [Pfit] varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO TempTable
    ([n], [id], [Name], [ShipDate], [Pfit])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'apple', '2018-04-14 00:00:00', '+'),
    (2, 1, 'apple', '2018-04-15 00:00:00', '+'),
    (3, 1, 'apple', '2018-04-16 00:00:00', '+'),
    (4, 1, 'apple', '2018-04-17 00:00:00', '-'),
    (5, 1, 'apple', '2018-04-18 00:00:00', '-'),
    (1, 2, 'bread', '2018-04-14 00:00:00', '-'),
    (2, 2, 'bread', '2018-04-15 00:00:00', '-'),
    (3, 2, 'bread', '2018-04-16 00:00:00', '+'),
    (1, 3, 'orange', '2018-04-14 00:00:00', '+'),
    (2, 3, 'orange', '2018-04-15 00:00:00', '+'),
    (3, 3, 'orange', '2018-04-16 00:00:00', '-'),
    (1, 4, 'tomato', '2018-04-14 00:00:00', '+'),
    (2, 4, 'tomato', '2018-04-15 00:00:00', '-'),
    (3, 4, 'tomato', '2018-04-16 00:00:00', '-')
;
```

[image]

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b60fa/1/0) : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b60fa/1/0

---

Hope it helps you :)